# Use oauth token provider through configuration

Tags: servicebus

Is there a way to configure the oauth access behaviour in a WCF configuration? I can not make it work. It is very easy in connection strings in a console app, but it is being a nightmare in the WCF configuration.

```
 <behavior name="securityBehaviorSts">

          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <windowsAuthentication>
                <stsUris>
                  <stsUri value="https://url:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/$STS/OAuth/" />
                </stsUris>
              </windowsAuthentication>
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
```

Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't found it